# How to pass props and call functions from "parent" to "child" in stateless component reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I tried to use props , but it works only if i pass props from parent to child like 
but it doesnt work   the other way

```
//Parent.js

import React from 'react'
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent(props) {
    return (
        <div>
        {props.greeting}
           <Child >
           <button onClick={props.Opentest}>Open Test</button>
           </Child>
        </div>
    )
}


//Child.js

import React from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  const greeting = "Hello";

  function openTest() {
    console.log("Done");
  }

  return  ;
}
```

In this code I would like to call function `openTest()` from Child in Parent component, and display variable `greeting`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options to handling such scenarios

First, which is a better way of handling is to have the button inside of `Child` component instead of pass it as a children

```
import React from "react";

export default function Child(props) {
  const greeting = "Hello";

  function openTest() {
    console.log("Done");
  }

  return  (
     <button onClick={this.Opentest}>Open Test</button>
  );
}
```

Second, a less preferred way is to use ref and call the child component method

```
export default function Parent(props) {
    const childRef = useRef(null)
    return (
        <div>
        {props.greeting}
           <Child ref={childRef}>
           <button onClick={() => childRef.current.Opentest()}>Open Test</button>
           </Child>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it works 
but the console shows :
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
i